# Locally bounded function definition

Tags: calculus

I don't get the idea of locally bounded functions. I know that locally bounded means that the specific function is bounded around every point. Also i know that all bounded functions are locally bounded by definition. However i can not prove that $f(x)=\frac{1}x$(unbounded) is not locally bounded or $f(x) = 2x+3 $(unbounded) is locally bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be a non-empty subset of $ \mathbb R$ and let $f:D \to \mathbb R$ be a function.

$f$ is locally bounded id for each $x_0 \in D$ there is a neighborhood $N_{x_0}$ and a constant $c_{x_0}$ such that

$$|f(x)| \le c_{x_0}$$

for all $x \in D \cap  N_{x_0}$.

For the function $f$ in your first example we have $D= \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ and $f$ is locally bounded.

For the function $f$ in your second example we have $D= \mathbb R $ and $f$ is locally bounded.

Comment: Thank you, Fred.